# Generate random numbers correctly

Tags: java, random

I would like to have 5 random numbers for every object I process. I process many objects (separately) and need to make sure that randomness is achieved across all numbers. If I process 5 objects, I will have 25 random numbers:

```
         RN1 RN2 RN3 RN4 RN5
Object 1   1   2   3   4   5
Object 2   6   7   8   9  10
Object 3  11  12  13  14  15
Object 4  16  17  18  19  20
Object 5  21  22  23  24  25
```

Questions are:

- for single object, does it make a difference if I create random number generator for every single number using current time in milliseconds as seed or  when I create one random number generator and get series of numbers using `nextDouble` in terms of randomness quality?
- once I process multiple objects and I take all first random numbers of all objects, will these will these form uniform random distribution (e.g. numbers 1, 6, 11, 16, 21) or this will be somehow broken?

My view is that it would be best to create one random number generator only (shared by all objects) so that whenever new random number is required I can call `nextDouble()` and get next number in sequence of random numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) class from Java.

It provides uniform distribution and avoids bottleneck as each of your threads will have its own copy.

Regarding them having different sequences, it's all about changing their seed. One common practice in that case is to see the generator with the Thread/Task/Process's identifier.

Comment: if you want more details on how to deal with random numbers in parallel/concurrent applications in Java, I've written a paper about that: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpe.3214/abstract

Answer (score 1):

> •for single object, does it make a difference if I create random
>   number generator for every single number using current time in
>   milliseconds as seed or when I create one random number generator and
>   get series of numbers using nextDouble in terms of randomness quality?

Don't use current time as seed for every number. The generation takes less time than the the resolution of current time in milliseconds.

Comment: it's a very bad practice to use a single generator as not only it will become a bottleneck if the application scales, but it doesn't ensure the results are reproducible, since you can't forecast the order in which threads will access the generator. it's dependent on the OS scheduling policy

Comment: @jopasserat Edited to stress the point I actually wanted to make, which is to not use the current time as seed for every call.

Comment: this point is worth mentioning. Although we don't know whether the OP expects reproducibility. For a game it could be fine.

Comment: @jopasserat I am assuming what the OP means is generating a bunch of random numbers in quick succession, resetting the seed manually each time to the current time. That is a bad idea. Using the current time as seed of a long sequence is not bad if you don't need reproducibility.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is probably to preliminary generate the required number of random numbers, save it into an array, and establish the rules of access order. In such way you have full control over the process. There is also no "loss of randomness".

Otherwise, if you launch several generators at once, they most likely will be seeded with the same value (system time by default), and if you use single generator accessed simultaneously by different threads, you need to pass an object of `Random` class, which is may be good but also can lead to the loss of reproducibility (I'm not sure, if this is crucial in your case).